# PHP: dice game until number is 1

Tags: php, if-statement

i have a course in PHP and i have been stuck on this assignment for a while now and i decided to ask help from here.

So the assignment goes like this "Make a PHP software that raffles a number until the number is 1" So the software has to guess a number until the number is 1. So the software must make a random number everytime and if it's 1 it stops.

I have tried couple of things, i have commented those  that didn't work.

```
<?php
    $i = rand(0, 10);
} else {
    echo "it should be one";
}

/*for ($i = mt_rand(0,2); $i != "1"; $i = mt_rand(0,2); ) {
    echo $i;
}
*/


/*function randomnumber() {
    rand(0,10);

}

if (randomnumber() == "1") {
    randomnumber();
    echo randomnumber();
} else {
    echo randomnumber();
} 
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going along the right lines, but perhaps the implementation has eluded you?

This is *one* of what are likely to be *a multitude of ways* of accomplishing this:

```
$r = 0;
$c = 0;

while ($r != 1) {
    $r = mt_rand(1, 6);
    echo 'I rolled ' . $r . '\n';
    $c++;
}
echo 'I finally rolled a ' . $r . '. It took me ' . $c . ' rolls!\n';
```

With the objective of *roll a dice until a 1 occurs*, you perform an infinite number of random rolls between 1 and 6 inclusive.  This continues until a 1 is rolled, at which point the `while` loop exits.

`$r` is the most recent roll, and `$c` keeps a count of how many rolls you did.

On each roll, the current number is output telling you what the computer rolled.

At the end, the computer tells you that it finally rolled a 1, and how many times it had to roll the dice to get it (`$c`).

The output will vary dependent upon the outcome of `mt_rand`, but one example is:

```
I rolled 4
I rolled 3
I rolled 6
I rolled 4
I rolled 4
I rolled 6
I rolled 4
I rolled 1
I finally rolled a 1. It took me 8 rolls!
```

Bear in mind that in this example, the newline character is output as `\n`. If your solution is on the web, you may wish to change this to `<br />` or something suitable for your output needs.

Comment: perfect case-usage for a while loop! I usually detest the sight of them, but this fits in nicely :)

Comment: This one worked perfectly, i learned a lot from this thank you so much!